# CSS for fluid Google Map with sidebar for search results

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I plan to include google map using javascript api to show search results for my site. 
Below is how i want the layout

On top would be header where i would display my common navigation panel .

Sidebar on left -it should be the search result shown as a list view . Its height should be equal to the browser window and on overflow it should scroll .

Map area -  It is the google map on which i would show the location of the search results . This should be such that it fills all the space available leaving the header and sidebar

basically it should look something like  [this website](http://www.foodtrucksmap.com/la/) or the normal [google places search](http://maps.google.com/maps?btnG=1&pws=0&q=food)

html code

```
<div class="wrapper_test" >
    <div class="full_map" id="search_map">
         <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:100%; height:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test_left" id="search_result" >
    </div>
</div>
```

css code

```
   .wrapper_test{
    overflow:auto;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.test_left{
    width:530px;
    background-color:#006666;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-style:auto;
    z-index:10;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.full_map{

    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFCC00;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-style:auto;
    position:relative;
    left:530px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    /*border:5px solid #fff;*/
}
```

I am not able to do it properly.the full map takes up the whole screen rather than the visible space on right of sidebar.

Please help  . Links for examples are invited .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change .full_map from having:

```
left: 530px;
```

to

```
padding-left: 530px;
```

So that your .full_map class looks like this:

```
.full_map{

    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFCC00;
    overflow:scroll;
    overflow-style:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:530px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    /*border:5px solid #fff;*/
}
```

Comment: You may want to mark the answer as "correct" to keep other SO members from inadvertently viewing this as something that needs an answer.

Comment: Here is a demo for this answer http://jsfiddle.net/jcarrion/c3n9jmaL/

Unfortunately it seems that the map div doesn't take full height.